Handling logic when there are many different objects in spring?
Everyone please help me answer this question. In the past, when I only had users and admins, I created a User table containing real information such as username, password, otp, role, etc. and a token table to store information about the user's login session. When the user logs in, I call userRepo findByEmail to verify. However, now my system has objects such as patients (users), doctors, lab staff, receptionists, cashiers, and admins, each of which contains separate information. So how should I create a table to store both authentication information and personal information of the objects. I still can't figure out how, for example, when a doctor logs in, the system will check the account and password, and then how to know who is logging in and call the corresponding repository to verify the information of that object. Please help me, I'm working on a project using spring boot. Thank you very much.

It would be a bad design to add all your additional attributes to your user table for all the user types, because then you would have some fields in this table that are unnecessary for most of the users. A patient may have attributes such as last checkup, which make no sense for doctors and the like.
It would make more sense to have a user_type field in your table and separate tables for each of your user types, so your specific user data could be inferred by user_type.
However, this is also problematic, because people may have multiple user types. For example a doctor may become ill, in which case said doctor becomes a patient while still being a doctor. Therefore, it makes more sense to have a table for each specific user type, so, besides your users table you would have

patients
doctors
lab_staff
receptionists
cashiers
admins

and each of these tables would contain the extra information you need, including the user_id field, which would be a foreign key referencing the corresponding users record.
Then you could implement a class for QualifiedUser, which would extend the class you have for the user and would have a field for corresponding user.
And you can then create classes like Patient, Doctor, LabStaff, Receptionist, Cashier, Admin, all of which would extend QualifiedUser, overriding the base table with the special user table and you could also have a List<QualifiedUser> field inside your User class, which, if hydrated would contain all the qualified user objects that relate to the given user.
Therefore all the methods of the user object would be inherited by the specific qualified user extensions where you could also override some of the method if they are to be performed differently for the given subclass as well as creating additional fields and methods.

I understand your point. I will separate the entities into distinct types such as Doctor (which will include experience, qualifications, and position), Patient (which will include last visit information), and so on. All of these will inherit from a base entity class that contains common attributes (ID, name, phone number, etc.).

However, I have an auth table that contains the IDs of these specific entities. When a user logs in, the system checks their email and password. If the credentials are valid, I want to fetch the corresponding information to return to the front-end.

My question is, how do I determine which specific entity is logging in so that I can call the appropriate repository and return the relevant information to the user? For example, if it's a doctor, I would call the doctorRepository, and if it's a receptionist, I would call the receptionistRepository, etc.

@TunazZz your Auth table is the basis. It is the very table you need for the authentication, independently of the user type. You will have the email and password in this auth table independently of whether a doctor or patient or etc. specific roles these user might have. On RDBMS level you can simply left join auth with all the specific user tables, like from auth left join doctors on auth.id = doctors.auth_id left join patients on auth.id = patients.auth_id left join ... and the result will be as follows:

@TunazZz you will have all the fields that you want from auth and all fields that you want from other entities. If the given auth is not a doctor, for example, then all fields for doctors will be null and if the given auth is a patient, then patients fields will have normal values. This way, with a single db. query you can get all the auth fields as well as all specific user fields that you intend and finding out what user types/roles the given auth has at the same time.

@TunazZz in terms of ORM, the list of specific users can be hydrated via lazy or eager fetching, depending on what your exact intention is. Read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Thanks for your suggestion with the query " from auth left join doctors on auth.id = doctors.auth_id left join patients on auth.id = patients.auth_id left join ...". I will write a nativeQuery to get user information and return it to the front end

Initially I had the idea to inject all repositories and use Role.equals("DOCTOR").... but now I have a better solution <3. Thank you very much

@TunazZz happy to help!
